# Semisimple Lie algebras and the commutator algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, hopf-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a associative unital $k$-algebra, where $\operatorname{char}k=0$. As is well-known, $A$ becomes a Lie algebra with respect to the commutator bracket $[x, y] = xy-yx$ for $x,y \in A$. Let $P$ denote a finite dimensional Lie subalgebra of $A$ with respect to this bracket. Suppose there exists a finite dimensional subspace $Q\subset A$ such that:
$P\subset Q$, $\operatorname{dim}(Q/P)\geq 2$ and $Q$ is a $P$-module (i.e. a representation of the Lie algebra $P$) via the action
$$
p\cdot q : = [p, q]
$$
for $p\in P, q\in Q$. Suppose further there exists a $P$-module homomorphism
$$\delta:Q\rightarrow P\otimes P$$
such that $\operatorname{ker}(\delta)=P$ (where the $P$-module action on $P\otimes P$ is given by $p\cdot(x\otimes y) =[p,x]\otimes y+x\otimes [p,y]$ for $p, x, y\in P$. If we assume that $P$ is a simple Lie algebra, can we always choose linearly independent elements $z,w \in Q\setminus{P}$ such that the expression 
\begin{equation}\label{ep}
(\delta\otimes\operatorname{id})([\delta(z), 1\otimes w+w\otimes 1] + [1\otimes z+z\otimes 1, \delta(w)])
\end{equation}
is non-zero in $A\otimes A\otimes A$?

My attempts:

For any $z, w\in Q$, write (in shorthand notation with indices omitted) $\delta(z)=\sum z_{1}\otimes z_{2}$ and $\delta(w)=\sum w_{1}\otimes w_{2}$. Then, using the fact that $P$ is the kernel of $\delta$, the above expression simplifies to
$$\sum \delta([z_{1}, w])\otimes z_{2} +\delta([z, w_{1}])\otimes w_{2}.$$

Given a $z\in Q\setminus{P}$, since $P$ is simple and $Q/P$ is a $P$-module, we can choose (I think) some $w$ in $Q\setminus{P}$ such that $[z_{1},w]\in Q\setminus P$ for some $z_{1}$ appearing in the expression for $\delta(z)$, but I'm not sure if this helps.

Edit: Original motivation for this question comes from Hopf algebras, which is why I've added that tag.

Comment: If this is motivated by Hopf algebras and/or Quantum groups, I'd suggest to add these tags.

Comment: This question is in fact motivated by Hopf algebras @Ycor, I'll add the tag

Comment: Crossposted from math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2021410/195021